# Dovecot - different authentification mechanisms for different users

Tags: email, dovecot, user-permissions

How can I make several groups of users and tune dovecot in a such way, that one group can use plain text auth (for example), second - APOP, third - MD5-CRYPT, etc?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it can be done because of the IMAP/POP login process.

When you start (for instance) an IMAP session, the server proposes you a series of [authorization mechanisms](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Authentication/Mechanisms). The client chooses one of them (possibly the best) during the login process, but is the client that makes the cohice.

You cannot force the server to present a limited set of authorization mechanisms BEFORE the user logs on.